# Asset URLs not HTTPS

Tags: assets, admin, nginx, ssl

I'm currently redirecting all requests to https. I've updated the `siteUrl` variable and all of my entry links have been correctly updated but the image links are still http.

When I go to the admin panel all of the CSS/JS files wont load because the site is trying to load them over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

[image]

```
server {

  listen   443;

  root /var/www/<url>/htdocs;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/rsa.key;
  server_name <url>;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  client_max_body_size 10M;


  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/remi/php55/root/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
  }

  # Errors

  error_page 404 /index.php;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /var/www/<url>/htdocs;
  }

  # Enable gzip compression
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  # Disable for IE < 6 because there are some known problems
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

  # Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending cached gzipped files to IE6
  gzip_vary on;

}
```

Comment: You doing anything in your `.htaccess` file that would need updating?

Comment: Added my whole vhost entry for port 443

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yii will check for the following server environment variables [when determining if it’s an SSL request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L573):

- **HTTPS** – should be set to “on”, “ON”, or “1”; or
- **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO** – should be set to “https” or “HTTPS”

Apparently this is a common issue when running PHP on Nginx, since that HTTPS env variable is only an Apache convention.

[Here’s an article that demonstrates how to fix it](http://blog.chrismeller.com/getting-php-https-detection-working-in-nginx). According to that, you just need to add the following to your server config.

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

You can probably add it right before/after your other `fastcgi_param` line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should the asset settings matter for the admin panel's JS/CSS files? So on my admin login page I'm getting an error loading `http://mysite.com/admin/resources/js/craft.js` even though my `siteUrl` is set to `//mysite.com`. Is this URL being built some other way?

Comment: @Jon Sorry, missed that the question was for the Control Panel. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Side note: nginx's ``$https`` variable should be [defined](http://serverfault.com/a/484460) as of 1.1.11 (which is pretty jurassic) so you could use ``fastcgi_param HTTPS $https`` as well.

Comment: see my reply below, though, for additional and/or more contempory information...

Answer (score 2):

An addition on this, probably for later versions of Craft than @brandonkelly's answer.

You also need to be careful where Asset definitions are made in the CP - specifically, under Settings>Assets>Volumes>yourAssetsName.

- the default or practice at some point was to have urls of the form:

```
    @web/your/resource/path
```

- however, as of Craft 3.1, a red-lettered advisory will appear, not to use @web alias here. Indeed, with the proper form, all will work as expected, and https will be used when appropriate:

```
    /your/resource/path
```

This works however you are accessing the url, even in CraftQL or element-api, because the path will always be root url-relative.