# Ensuring Image transforms use https

Tags: image-transforms, ssl

I'm trying to get rid mix content warnings for https connection. The SSL certificate is installed and working fine but my image transforms are being requested over http hence the warning messages.

Looking into the docs I have tried:

```
url={{image.getUrl(thumb, null, 'https')}}
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

ok - just figured it out after reading Brandon's answer here [Asset URLs not HTTPS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11797/asset-urls-not-https)

The missing piece was to set the url setting of the asset source to root relate e.g. `/uploads/images`

Clear the cache and all sorted!

Comment: Spot on, the asset source URL change did the trick (under `/admin/settings/assets/sources/X`)

Comment: Also please see an additional step you may need, in https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/29300/85